# Remove x-axis and y-axis from Zingchart

Tags: javascript, charts, zingchart

I want to completely remove, not hide, the x and y-axis in my Zingcharts. I have a graph that does not need an x or y axis, and although I can hide them, they are taking up valuable space, which results in a compressed graph. Is there anyway to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sounds like you may be setting scales to visible: false, but there is still a lot of space around the chart where these items used to be.

You can eliminate this space by setting items to visible:false, setting associated line-color attributes to "none" and adding:

`"plotarea":{
    "margin":"0 0"
  }`

to your JSON. Below is an example with this spacing removed using the method described above. Click the "run code snippet" button to see the resulting chart.

```js
var myConfig = {
  "type": "line",
  "scale-x":{
    "line-color":"none",
    "item":{
      "visible":false
    },
    "tick":{
      "line-color":"none"
    }
  },
  "scale-y":{
    "line-color":"none",
    "item":{
      "visible":false
    },
    "tick":{
      "line-color":"none"
    }
  },
  "plotarea":{
    "margin":"0 0"
  },
  "series": [
    {
      "values":[20,40,25,50,15,45,33,34]
    },
    {
      "values":[5,30,21,18,59,50,28,33]
    },
    {
      "values":[30,5,18,21,33,41,29,15]
    },
    ]
};

zingchart.render({ 
 id : 'myChart', 
 data : myConfig, 
 height: 400, 
 width: 600 
});
```

```html
<html>
 <head>
 <!--Assets will be injected here on compile. Use the assets button above-->
  <script src= 'https://cdn.zingchart.com/2.1.2/zingchart.min.js'></script>
  <script> zingchart.MODULESDIR = 'https://cdn.zingchart.com/2.1.2/modules/';</script>
 
 <!--Inject End-->
 </head>
 <body>
  <div id='myChart'></div>
 </body>
</html>
```

If you're setting scales to visible:false, that may create some issues. Instead, adjusting the styling so they are simply not seen can prevent conflicts with other functionality. I'm on the ZingChart team, so please let me know if this answers your question or if you would like additional clarification.

Comment: Sure thing: add the guide object to scale-x and scale-y, and then inside the object, set line-width to 0. Here is a demo -- http://demos.zingchart.com/view/F7B6LX6Y 

As a heads up, you can get all the items associated to scales in the JSON attributes syntax in the ZingChart docs -- http://www.zingchart.com/docs/json-attributes-syntax/